# fatal error: folder/include: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

I have coded in visual studio before just fine but I have recently tried to try out visual studio code, I tried to first do a simple hello world but every time I try to compile my code within visual studio code I get **Test1.cpp:13:1: fatal error: folder/include: No such file or directory
}
^
compilation terminated.** my only guess is I've installed MinGW incorrectly however I have reinstalled it multiple times and it seems to be running as I can call its version in the command prompt any help would be great.

[image: Rev]

Comment: Please elaborate your question and share the code you have written

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code that you have written!

You can also try to compile the .cpp file in cmd and run it with command-

-> g++ *filename*.cpp -o *filename*.exe

-> *filename*.exe

P.S. These commands should be written in the same directory where you have created these files. Eg. C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CPP Files>g++ helloWorld.cpp -o helloWorld.exe
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CPP Files>helloWorld.exe

Comment: The question is related to the issue encountered in visual studio. You are mentioning about terminal way of compiling.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that **folder/include** cannot be found. This could be is a configuration error. Check your configuration to properly provide existing folder with absolute path in the visual studio.